# What Adaptations To Human Physiology Would Be Necessary To Be Able To Use Echolocation Underwater?

Tags: biology, creature-design, underwater

After watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=08smCjKWNL0) video about humans being able to use echolocation, I began to wonder if this same idea could be used underwater. Could a human be able to use echolocation underwater without any extra abilities? If they could then it would be amazing to create humans or human like creatures that have learned this ability and are able to use it.

I hope this is enough information on what I'm asking, but if it is not please tell me and I will edit the question. Thanks!

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Thanks for telling me. You're right changing it would probably be good. Also you had helped me before on my first question so thanks again!

Comment: From this article on National Geographic it seems like with whales and dolphins, mammals that can do this underwater, the ear bones have to be separate from the rest of the skull so they don't just vibrate with it. Also they use the jaw as a means for the sound to travel instead of the ear canal. https://www.nationalgeographic.com/animals/article/150311-whales-hearing-underwater-ears-echolocation-ocean-animals-science

Answer (score 2):

A human would have to have a bulbous skull with a fatty substance in which to receive sound signals. Also the ability to emit high pitch clicks and whistles much like a dolphin. The human would also need to have the ability to translate the signals into images in order to determine shape and size of the item that is being located.

Comment: Very nice first post, I agree with your solution totally. Welcome to worldbuilding, please partake of our [tour] and refer to the [help] as and when for guidance as to our ways, enjoy the site.

Comment: You mean a [melon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melon_(cetacean)).

Answer (score 0):

It would need the human to be able to emit and receive sounds directly in/from the water, without having to go through the air/water interface which, due to the large mismatch in acoustic impedance, makes for large losses in the transmission of sound. This would likely mean using their bones.

This already partially happens (I happened to brush my teeth with an electric toothbrush while wearing a noise cancelling headset, and I could feel the buzz going through my jaws) but not in an intentional way, so some optimization would be needed.

Comment: So what would have to change in their physiology to cause this to work? If you've already answered this, then I don't understand.